# creating Visual Studio shortcuts keys

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

There are some things that I do a lot in a new project, for example, entering in a simple call to the Google AJAX API to include jQuery. Can I somehow map my own shortcut combo in VS to have it insert this is when I enter my shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You would have to create a Macro that inserts the current text where the cursor is.  For example, to insert a timestamp for the highlighted text (like for Migratordotnet) I have this macro in the MyMacros project:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Module Tools
    Public Sub DateTimeStamp()
        Dim textSelection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
        textSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        textSelection.Insert(String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", DateTime.Now))
    End Sub
End Module
```

2) Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment/Keyboard -> Highlight your Macro in the "Show commands containing:" selection -> in the "Press shortcut keys" box do the key combination/chord you want to associate to the macro.  As for the "Use new shorcut in:" section, the Global option will apply to every document type in Visual Studio, no matter where the focus is.  So for my example above, the command is found at `Macros.MyMacros.Tools.DateTimeStamp`.

Comment: What scheme do I apply it to and what section? I chose `(Default)` and `Global` and it didn't work. I saved my Macro as jQuery in MyMacros. I mapped the key command and saved and closed and it doesn't work.

Comment: I added some additional information and example of how I've used it.  Does that help clarify the steps?

Comment: With the code it seemed to work. When I did a macro recording it did -- not sure why. Thanks!